# add prop base on condition to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
<MyComponent something={somethingIsTrue} />
```

How to add `something` as prop to `MyComponent` if `somethingIsTrue`? I still wouldn't want something=undefined or `something=false` because it's still been added to MyComponent. I want it to be

> not added as prop

if `somethingIsTrue` is falsely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to try this but something like this should do the trick.

```
const conditionalProps = shouldHaveProps ? {something: somethingIsTrue} : {};

<MyComponent {...conditionalProps} />
```

Comment: found something like this `<MyComponent {...(shouldHaveProps  && {something: somethingIsTrue})}/>`

Comment: @AliciaY Yes that is a valid method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the dynamic expression in JSX for the desired result

```
<MyComponent {...(somethingIsTrue ? {something:somethingIsTrue} : {})}/>
```

Comment: I like this one-liner

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can do as:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
const something = true;
const props = something ? { something: something } : null;
return <MyComponent {...props} />;
```

**2)** You can toggle component with pass argument if `something` is `truthy`

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
const something = true;

return something 
          ? <MyComponent something={something} /> 
          : <MyComponent />;
```

Comment: the 2nd option is not a good solution, imagine you have more props

Comment: Agree, Just wanted to tell you all possible solution